# validate form data using database

Tags: java, html, database, jsp, web

I am working on a java project using jsp and I am trying to validate user info from the database and if it is correct I want to redirect the user to the home page

This is my sign in form I am using the customer id as there username

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <%@page import="java.io.PrintWriter"%>
   <%@page import="java.sql.*"%> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Sign In Page</title>
    </head>   
<body>
        <h1>Sign In</h1>
        <form action="SignIn.jsp"  method="post">
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>Username</td> 
                    <td> <input type="text" name="username"></td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Password</td> 
                    <td> <input type="password" name="password"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td> 
                    <td> <input type="submit" value="Sign In"><input type="reset" name="Clear"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

        <%
  try {
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ProjectDB", "admin1", "1234");
            String username=request.getParameter("username");
            String password=request.getParameter("password");
            String query = "Select cid, password From customers;";
      PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(query);
      st.executeUpdate();             
                  conn.close();
              } catch (SQLException ex) {
                  ex.printStackTrace();
              }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is how I created my customers table in the database

```
create table customers (cid integer primary key Generated Always as Identity, password varchar(50));
```

Comment: You want a `PreparedStatement` and `executeQuery` with `if(rs.next())`

Comment: @g00se I don't really get your point I already have prepared statement

Comment: Yes but call `setParameter`

Comment: Golly, what you're trying to do is actually quite difficult.  And it is difficult due to timing.  JSPs are compiled and their html is first created on the server.  Then that html is delivered to the client (most likely a browser) and then rendered by the browser.  My guess is that you're expecting to read the values from the html input fields.  However, the only way for your sql to execute is to actually submit the page after the fields have been filled out.  I would recommend looking into MVC via Servlets and JSP.

Comment: And I am almost certain that this is for a personal/school project, but storing passwords as plain text in the database is strongly discouraged .  A reasonable way to encrypt the passwords is to use a one way hash like [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).